# What is a regex to change indentation of any lines that come between two unique strings, to match the indentation of the first and drop the second?

Tags: regex

How can I write a regex to find xBxCxDExDExDE...xF with any number of xDE's up to a terminal character F, and replace it with xBxExExExE... where:

- all occurrences of D get removed
- E is `.*\n`
- all E's are actually different strings that should still be there after the replace
- x is `.*` (whatever the first line starts with before B)
- all x's are actually the same exact string

Starting string:

```objectivec
        some text; // context
        some more text; // context
        strongify(self);
        if (self) {
            // Handle error
            if (error) {
                AlertWithError(error);
            } else {
                if (uploadingImage) {
                    [self logImageUploadWithInfo:uploadInfo startTime:startTime];
                }
                
                // Call optional protocol method on completion
                [(id<Thing>)controller doSomething];
            }
            
            // Signal
            [self done];
        }
        even more text; // context
        yadayadayada; // context
```

... where x is eight spaces  `{8}`, B is `strongify(self);\n`, C is `if (self) {\n`, D is four spaces  `{4}`, F is `}`, and E is everything after xD on each of the lines after C. Lines that should not be "found" by the regex pattern are marked with `// context`.

The regex should let me do a search and replace where the substitution is like $1$2$3, such that the result would be:

```
        some text; // context
        some more text; // context
        strongify(self);
        // Handle error
        if (error) {
            AlertWithError(error);
        } else {
            if (uploadingImage) {
                [self logImageUploadWithInfo:uploadInfo startTime:startTime];
            }
        
            // Call optional protocol method on completion
            [(id<Thing>)controller doSomething];
        }
        
        // Signal
        [self done];
        even more text; // context
        yadayadayada; // context
```

As long as it does what I need, I will accept any answer even if it uses a totally different substitution string or a different (but 100% equivalent) conceptualization of the problem than `xABxCxDExDExDE...xF -> xAxExExExE...`

### What I tried so far:

`( *)(strongify\(self\);\n)(?: .*if ?\(self\) ?\{\n)((?:    )(\1.*?\n)*)(?:\1\})`

... but the problem with this is that `(?:    )` gets captured even though it's a non-capturing group, so `$1$2$3` results in the lines after the first captured line all being indented one level too far.

This seems like a bug in regex. Why is it capturing a non-capturing group? Bonus points if you can explain why that makes sense or why it's good for enclosing capture groups to convert non-capturing groups into capturing groups.

I also tried not wrapping `(?:    )(\1.*?\n)*` in a capture group but then we run into the problem that `$3` now only gives         `[self done];` because capture groups aren't cumulative.

So it seems I'm looking for some kind of way to have a cumulative capture group.

Conceptually I would like to solve this by spawning a child regex that gets fed just the lines that need to have their indentation reduced, since in that case it becomes a simple multi-line regex.

Comment: Even if it's possible with a regular expression, I don't think a regular expression is the correct tool here. Just write a program that reads the lines one at a time and reindents them according to the desired logic.

Comment: @KenWhite Eh I was just trying to be nice. Deleted those comments. So is the consensus that regex does not support this kind of operation? I understand that it would be more "correct" to solve such a problem with multiple steps rather than a single search & replace, but the reason I am asking for a regex solution is because when editing code my IDE, the search-and-replace feature makes it straightforward to use regex but not so for multi-step scripted operations. I realize a shell script could work, but it feels like this *should* be possible to accomplish in regex, since I can get very close.